# Running different programs on multiple cores

Tags: r, snowfall

Hopefully this is a simple question I've overlooked an answer to, but in my searches this morning I've been fruitless.

I have four cores on my computer, and want to concurrently run different programs (loops) in R over multiple cores.  If I open up four R sessions, will they automatically be places on different cores, or do I need to figure out a way to do this with snowfall?

I have successfully used snowfall before to run the same program, but with different values before.  But would snowfall allow me to run completely different programs on different cores?  Could I set up each simulation loop to be a different function (i.e: func1, func2, func3, func4), and then have snowfall assign each function to a different core?

Thanks for any help

Comment: why don't you just do an experiment and see what happens?

Comment: Hi Ben, unfortunately I can't do a proper test as I am in the middle of a fairly large simulation using up my cores.  Trying to design my next simulation while the current one is running so I can be ready to go.  Seems like I will follow Henrik's suggestion of just using multiple R sessions without needing snowfall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how it is on different OSs, but on windows your OS takes care of this. So you can open as many R sessions as you want and they will be distributed across the cores (with each process taking maximally one core). If you open more R sessions than you have CPUs, then obviously some will not be able to use a full CPU.

So no need to use snowfall here.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. If you have completely different things to compute, `snowfall` or `parallel` is unnecessary and opening up different R consoles the way to go, as proposed by the OP. Distribution across cores is then done by the OS.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to answer this question is:

1. Create four functions that each take a minute or two to run
2. Use `snowfall`
3. Look at your CPUs processor usage.

But to answer your question, yes they will be distributed across cores.

It might be easier to just use the `parallel` package that comes with R 2.15

Comment: I'd always argue that `parallel` is easier because it a) comes with all recent versions and b) is effectively a rewrite / code review of the better parts of `snow` and `multicore`.

Comment: The all recent versions is the clincher.